# Detecting specific key in low level keyboard hook

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook

I'm creating an application that places an icon on the system tray that changes its appearance based on the state of the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key. The issue I'm facing is that the hook only works correctly after a key other than Caps Lock is pressed, since that key flips the check after the hook is passed through, making the icon display the wrong state incorrectly.

I would need a way to detect when the Caps Lock key is pressed inside the hook to flip the detected state.

```
private static NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
private static bool CapsPressed = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock);
static Icon
    AppIcon = CapsIndicator.Properties.Resources.AppIcon,
    OnIcon =  CapsIndicator.Properties.Resources.OnIcon,
    OffIcon = CapsIndicator.Properties.Resources.OffIcon;

static void UpdateIcon() {
    notifyIcon.Icon = CapsPressed ? OnIcon : OffIcon;
}

// Hook initializing & other stuff here

private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr) WM_KEYDOWN) {
        CapsPressed = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock);
        UpdateIcon();
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution isn't very straight-forward, but the key code can be revealed using the `lParam` pointer argument. You can do this by accessing the 32-bit integer it's pointing to with [`Marshal.ReadInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eawzfdz5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), then, you need to cast it to the `Keys` type, and finally compare this value with `Keys.CapsLock` (or any other key you like):

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr) WM_KEYDOWN) {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

        CapsPressed = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock);
        // Flip the detected value if CapsLock is pressed
        if ((Keys) vkCode == Keys.CapsLock) CapsPressed = !CapsPressed;

        UpdateIcon();
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: That tends to work, it is not technically correct.  Other hooks can prevent the key from getting used.  Low odds, not zero.  Using the form's BeginInvoke() or SynchronizationContext.Current.Post() methods are excellent ways to run code later.

Comment: @HansPassant In my case the application does not have a form open until one is called from the tray icon's right click menu. The only way I can catch the keys is through a global catcher.

Comment: That's why I mentioned SynchronizationContext.

Comment: @HansPassant: You're amazing. I'd never even heard of .Net's SynchronizationContext class, and it's just what I've been looking for, without even realizing that I was looking for it.